# what is the role of TypeModel.Create?

Tags: c#, serialization, protobuf-net

First of all excuse me if this is a noob question - but I'm new to `protobuf-net`.

I noticed some people use `TypeModel.Create()` when serializing with `protobuf-net`, while others just call `Serializer` directly (meaning using the default singleton `RuntimeTypeModel.Default`).

What is the difference? I would assume if I reuse the same `RuntimeTypeModel.Default` all the time, I'd get some performance benefits, but what do I give up in exchange?

If I already know the `Type` of my object when I invoke the serialization, which approach is better?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

k; the methods on `Serializer.*` now work primarily as a shortcut to `RuntimeTypeModel.Default.*`. There are three reasons that they still exist:

- convenience
- lots of existing example code
- v1 API compatibility

Most people will only ever need a single model. However, the system supports different parallel models with different configurations *if you need that*. In most usage that is unlikely, however: it does make it *vastly* more testable, as I can reset the entire system simply be using a different model instance. So: reasons that you can (if you want, which most people won't) have multiple model instances:

- testing, mainly me :)
- migrating between different layouts / versions

As an aside, the `TypeModel` API is also exposed if you are using the "precompile" feature (targetted mainly at things like phone devices). This generates an assembly with a custom model type, usable via:

```
var serializer = new MyCustomSerializer();
```

where `MyCustomSerializer : TypeModel` - although in this case it won't be a `RuntimeTypeModel`.